# Tkinter Text Check If Index Has Tag

Tags: python, text, tkinter, tags, character

I would like for my program to check if an index in a Text widget has a tag attached to it, I would then like for it to insert a different character based on the tag. This is following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055505/python-tkinter-text-formatting-markers/) as my work around.
At the moment, I have the program searching for spaces, tabs, and newlines. It then applies a different tag to it based on what it was. These tags for the moment just have basic primary colors as a background to check if the tags work, and they do.

So, my question: is there a command in Tkinter to check if an index has an applied tag so that I can have it then insert the needed character into that spot and remove it if the index does not have the tag?

If you require a little bit of code to get an understanding of what I have, here's what you'll need (this will not function on it's own, it will need editing).

```
mainText.tag_configure ("SPACE", background = "yellow")

def FormattingSpaces ():
    for i in mainText.get (1.0, END):
        first = 1.0
        while (True):
            first = mainText.search (" ", first, "end")
            if not first:
                break
            last = first + "+" + str (len (" ")) + "c"
            mainText.tag_add ("SPACE", first, last)
            first = last
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `tag_names` method of the text widget to get the list of tags for that index. For example:

```
tags = mainText.tag_names("1.0")
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know if that was how I would do it.